# what is the maximum number of records to store in an IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I am working on a project where I have to provide a form which can have around 7000 fields - :D
It is like up to 25 products and each product to have 64 sub products and each sub product can have up to 7 fields, out of which only 3 are mandatory.
I want to make sure that its saved in IndexedDB first and sent to server DB after clicking the Save button.

Is there any limit in storing that much data in IndexedDB? I know about the size limits of the IndexedDB, but not sure about storing so much information there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a limit on object count directly. The limit is the total amount of data. You would have to get your average object size, multiply that by the total number of objects, and compare that to the size limit to get an estimate of the maximum number of objects you can store.

There are practical limits on the size of a single object. I believe it has to be transferable between processes, e.g. via interprocess communication (IPC). You might be looking at 1MB or less per object or something like this? It might vary by operating system or browser. Unsure.